# Error requestAnimationFrame in ie9 any alternate solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, internet-explorer-9

I am creating Canvas (I am new to this Canvas) object cylinder this is working fine Chrome & Firefox but when i open the  same file in ie9.

I am getting error as 'requestAnimationFrame' is undefined

When i google the error it says requestAniationFrame won't work on ie9.

Can any body help me with this do we have any alternate way to solve this.

and here is my code

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        var degreeAngle = 0;
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        function drawRotatedCylinder(x, y, w, h, degreeAngle) {
            context.save();
            context.translate(x + w / 10, y + h / 10);
            context.rotate(degreeAngle * Math.PI / 180);
            drawCylinder(-w / 10, -h / 10, w, h);
            context.restore();
        }   
function animate() {
        //requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        drawRotatedCylinder(100, 100, 180, 180, degreeAngle++);
}
```

Kindly help me for the above solution

Thanks Regards
Maha

Comment: https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671

Comment: You didn't really search for it, did you?!

Comment: hi @A.Wolff i really searched it but i was not able to find the solution

Comment: @user3820621 So then, i apologize, see here for better explaination: http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Answer (score 22):

Erik Möller developed a robust polyfill that Paul Irish now hosts in his [blog post about requestAnimationFrame](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/). If you use this code, you can use requestAnimationFrame in pretty much any browser transparently:

```
(function() {
    var lastTime = 0;
    var vendors = ['webkit', 'moz'];
    for(var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'RequestAnimationFrame'];
        window.cancelAnimationFrame =
          window[vendors[x]+'CancelAnimationFrame'] || window[vendors[x]+'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
    }

    if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
        window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
            var currTime = new Date().getTime();
            var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
            var id = window.setTimeout(function() { callback(currTime + timeToCall); },
              timeToCall);
            lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
            return id;
        };

    if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
        window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
            clearTimeout(id);
        };
}());
```

Comment: The issue solved i have put the above javascript before my code it was working fine ie9 thanks once again for all